# how to count the buyer with special condition

Tags: mysql-workbench

so i have a table which contain data buyer who doing transaction per day in a month, so how do i get the buyer where the total transaction in a month >= 600k, this is my syntax

```
SELECT
    b.buyer_id
FROM order_buyer b
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_buyer d
            WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND
                  d.createdAt >= '2017-10-01' AND d.createdAt < '2018-01-01') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_buyer d
            WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND
                  d.createdAt >= '2017-10-01' AND d.createdAt < '2018-01-01' ) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_buyer d
                WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND d.createdAt < '2017-01-01') group by buyer_id;
```

Comment: Which column has amount? Please share the DB structure with sample data and expected output for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple query using `HAVING` clause should work for you.

```
SELECT buyer_id, amount
FROM order_buyer
WHERE createdAt >= '2018-10-01'
AND createdAt < '2018-11-01'
GROUP BY buyer_id
HAVING SUM(amount) >= 600000;
```

Comment: but what if i want to look at the buyer id who doing transaction upper than 600000 in just month 11?

Comment: You can change the date range to the required month and add `AND` clause to filter for a particular buyer.